# JavaScript nested loop unexpected result

Tags: javascript, nested-loops

I would expect the following code to return the result (matrix)

[ [0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0] ]

```
function zeroArray(m, n) {
  let newArray = [];
  let row = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    
    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      row.push(0);
    }
    newArray.push(row);
  }
  return newArray;
}

let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
console.log(matrix);
```

but it returns:
[ [0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0] ]

I cannot see how `row` is [0,0,0,0,0,0] for each iteration of the outer loop?

I see `row` iterating from [0,0] to [0,0,0,0] to [0,0,0,0,0,0] and pushing to `newArray` on each instance.  However, this is evidently wrong.

Can anyone explain this result for me?

Comment: This happens because arrays are reference types in JavaScript (meaning when you do `newArray.push(row)` you are only pushing a reference to `row` so when its value changes, it changes everywhere).

Comment: Ok, I get it! I can see this being something that you need to watch out for.. by value or by reference knock on effects.  I wasn't fully aware that the reference was keep to the variable after pushing into the array, I thought it was new memory space..  but clearly not.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could push a copy of `row`. This eliminates the same object reference.

```js
function zeroArray(m, n) {
  let newArray = [];
  let row = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    
    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      row.push(0);
    }
    newArray.push([...row]);
  }
  return newArray;
}

let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
console.log(matrix);
```

Answer (score 2):

The bounds checking was wrong in the inner loop according to your output, in each iteration of the outer loop allocate a new array of `i * 2` length.

You can use [`Array.prototype.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) to simplify your code more.

```js
function zeroArray(m, n) {
  const newArray = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
    const row = new Array(i * 2).fill(0);
    newArray.push(row);
  }
  return newArray;
}

let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
console.log(matrix);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop is run for every value of n, then again for every value of m in the out loop.

For every number in M > Run every number in N and push to row. 3*2 gives 6 results in that table.